# setState from loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

so .i can't find a way to handle changes and set the state in the right way
i tried many methods but none of theme is working
and is it a right way to solve this kind of many input !

```
const Add = () => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({
    name: '',
    sexe: '',
    age: '',
    antecedents: '', 
    localisation: '', 
    stade: '',
    Chirurgie: '',
    traitementMedical: '',
    ligneDeTraitement: '',
    effetSecondaireType: '',
    effetSecondaireGrade: '',
  });
  const onChange = (e, o) => {
   // here

  };
  const renderInput = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
    renderInput.push(
      <TextInput
        key={Object.keys(obj)[i]}
        placeholder={Object.keys(obj)[i]}
        placeholderTextColor="gray"
        onChangeText={e => onChange(e, Object.keys(obj)[i])}
        defaultValue={obj[i]}
      />,
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{flex: 1, margin: 10}}>{renderInput}</View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Here is kindly not a coding service.

Comment: i didnt add the code i have tried

Comment: You never call `setObj` in your code.  In order to successfully set the state, you have to call the function that sets the state.  Note also that the only loop in this code executes when the component renders.  So setting the state there would cause an infinite re-render loop.

Comment: Can you please mention the expected output and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You want to construct the new state object as whatever you had before, plus the one changed value.

```
const onChange = (value, key) => {
  setObj(
    {
      ...obj,
      [key]: value
    }
  );
};

const renderInput = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  renderInput.push(
    <TextInput
      key={Object.keys(obj)[i]}
      placeholder={Object.keys(obj)[i]}
      placeholderTextColor="gray"
      onChangeText={e => onChange(e, Object.keys(obj)[i])}
      defaultValue={obj[i]}
    />,
  );
}
```

Also note you can simplify the loop considerably by using `.map` instead.

```
const inputs = Object.entries(obj).map(
  ([key, value]) => (
    <TextInput
      key={key}
      placeholder={value}
      placeholderTextColor="gray"
      onChangeText={newValue => onChange(newValue, key}
      defaultValue={value}
    />
  )
);
```

Comment: You have a leaking closure or whatever its called: `onChangeText={e => onChange(e, Object.keys(obj)[i])}` the i will always be the last. So your proposed simplification is in fact not just only simpler, but the other approach is not even working correctly.

Comment: @Martin if I understand what you're getting at, that behavior only applies when using `var` in the loop. The `let` loop should work fine as is, although the `map` simplification is much better.

Comment: You are absolutely right; I just checked it and the behavior is different for `var` and `let`. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

your `onChange` should be something like:

```
const onChange = (e, o) => {
  // here
  setObj({...obj, [o]: e.target.value})
};
```